# I've tried to console log the request body of a form. But not all the input fields are displayed. One textarea is missing in the log

Tags: html

```
<form action="/contact/submit" method="POST">
  <br style="clear:both">
  <p style="margin-bottom: 25px; text-align: center; font-size: 20px"><b>Contact Form</b></p>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="mobile" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" type="textarea" id="message" placeholder="Message" maxlength="140"></input>
    <span class="help-block"><p id="characterLeft" class="help-block ">You have reached the limit</p></span>
  </div>    
  <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Submit Form</button>
</form>
```

What I get when I console log the req.body of this post using console.log(req.body) is
    { name: 'aa',
      email: 'xyz@gmail.com',
      mobile: '232',
      subject: 'yo',
      submit: '' }
But not the the message.

Answer (score 2):

Textarea is not a type of input, it's an element itself...

```
<textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea>
```

Comment: Same goes for `<select>`

Comment: Hey! Thanks. I've removed type="textarea", wrote type="text" and gave the tag, a name. It works just fine now.